# Missing Something - A linkbox containing 4 images and 4 links inside a link banner only displays 3 images after change to one image

Tags: hyperlink, footer, banner

I needed to change the 4th picture and link today.  After doing so, only the first three pictures display.  I changed the image, and the linkbox code on the 3 affected html pages.  Why are Only the 3 unchanged images visible in this link box inside a  link banner?  I am missing something. Where are the actual images being called out to populate the link banner?  None of the 4 image file names are in this code.

Here is the code:

See letsgetem-charters.com.  Thank you!

Comment: I was not able to put the code in the question.

Comment: Can't you provide a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: thank you.  I went to make a fiddle, and found the error in style.css  If you had not sent me there, I would still be fiddling around with my error.